# Angle estimation with mpu5060:

Tags: robotics, kalman-filter

I am using mpu5060, which is 6dof sensor "3 axis gyroscope and 3 axis accelerometer" for my two wheeled balancing robot project, I placed it as close to the center of mass as I could "its hard to tell"
I used kalman filter to reduce the measurement noise, but my problem is that moving the robot forward and backward without rotation are affecting the measurement of the gyroscope.
I tried to use newton-raphson to calculate the angle from the sensor measurements but I still have the same problem.
I also tried replacing kalman filter with complementary filter, which gave me the same problem.

I used the kalman filter from [this](http://www.linushelgesson.se/2012/04/pitch-and-roll-estimating-kalman-filter-for-stabilizing-quadrocopters/) page:

I tried different values for covariance noise matrices "Q & R"
big numbers for Q1 Q2, around 50, and small Q3 which is for the gyroscope bias.
 measurements noise r1 and r2 are low "how much do we trust measurement of angle and angular velocity"

Changing Q1 and Q2 to low numbers did not help also